# manipulating strings in an array java

Tags: java, arrays

so I am supposed to initialize a 10x10 matrix and fill it with different patterns such as:

```
........................ 
........................ 
 ... ... ... ... ... ... 
 ... ... ... ... ... ... 
  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  .. 
  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  .. 
   .   .   .   .   .   . 
   .   .   .   .   .   .
```

how would I would go about controlling the number of times the . character appears in each cell. I know I can loop through the matrix and after the next even numbered row I could decrease the number of times the . character appears but how do I go about doing this.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far, or are you just looking for general advice?

Comment: to be honest, I'm looking for general advice. not necessarily the solution but just some sort of idea because other than hardcoding it I have no clue where to start :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the update on the question.  here is some code that I believe does what you are looking for.

```
  public static String printDots(int numDots)
      {
        String dots = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < numDots; i++)
         {
        dots += ".";
    }

return dots;
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{

    String[][] matrix = new String[10][10];
    int numDots = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
    {

        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
        {
                matrix[i][j] = printDots(numDots);
        }
        if(i%2 != 0)
            numDots--;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j= 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
            System.out.println(matrix[i][j]);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: for the first two rows, there are 4 .s. the next two rows have 3 .s and etc till the last two rows where all the cells are blank

Comment: FYI - the last for loop is just a check to make sure the matrix outputs what you would like, it does not actually help the code at all.  If you like the answer, please accept as an answer and upvote :)  Of course, if this is not what you intended, please let me know and I can change it

Comment: @JuanBattini Did this code work for you? If so, please accept as an answer/upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

By the nature of arrays/matrices, you will probably want to use loops.  In your problem, you could use one loop to traverse down rows of the matrix.  To fill the columns you might use another loop.  Some pseudocode might look like

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Rows; i++) //standard indexing loop
    var pattern = determinePrintingPattern(row)
    print(pattern)
```

In your problem in particular, it looks like the printing of dots happens in 6 groups of 4, with decreasing dots every even row.  So

```
function returnPattern determinePrintingPattern(int row) //might look like pseudocoded
    for 6 iterations
        print 4 - row/2 dots //integer division is desirable and will truncate (drop the decimal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem down.

Write a method that creates a string of length `length` with `dots` dots positioned correctly within it, ie with a signature like:

```
String dotty(int length, int dots) {
    // your code here
}
```

Get that working, then write a method to create an array of these Strings:

```
String[] dottyArray(int length, int dots, int size) {
    String[] result = new String[size];
    Arrays.fill(result, dotty(length, dots);
    return result;
}
```

Then create a loop to call that method to fill a 2D array:

```
String[][] dottyGrid(int length, int columns, int rows) {
    String[][] result = new String[rows][];
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) 
        result[row] = dottyArray(length, (rows - row / 2) / 2, columns);
    return result;
}
```

The one small "trick" is that integer division truncated the fractional part, which neatly makes the dots amount step by 2.